# Persisting JSON change via AttributeConverter to database using Quarkus and Hibernate

Tags: java, json, hibernate, quarkus

I'm trying to persist changes to database in the following way:

#### Entities

I have a JPA entity with JSON data type:

```
@Entity
public class TestEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Convert(converter = TestConverter.class)
    @Column(name = "data", columnDefinition = "JSON")
    private TestData data;

    ...
}
```

With `TestData` entity defined like this:

```
public class TestData {
    private String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        TestData testData = (TestData) o;
        return Objects.equals(value, testData.value);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(value);
    }
}
```

#### Converter

Converter for `TestData` is implemented like this:

```
@Converter
public class TestConverter implements AttributeConverter<TestData, String> {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestConverter.class);
    private static final Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create();

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(TestData attribute) {
        logger.debug("To JSON: {}", attribute);
        return jsonb.toJson(attribute);
    }

    @Override
    public TestData convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        logger.debug("From JSON: {}", dbData);
        return jsonb.fromJson(dbData, TestData.class);
    }
}
```

#### Service

Finally I have a service which is trying to modify an existing entity in the database:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class Service {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Service.class);

    @Inject
    public EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional
    public void modify(Long id) {
        TestEntity entity = entityManager.find(TestEntity.class, id);
        entity.getData().setValue("new");
        logger.debug("Modified: {}", entity);
    }
}
```

#### Configuration

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:33003/test?sessionVariables=FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull" />
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="db-user" />
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="db-pass" />
<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="update"/>

<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect"/>
<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit" value="false"/>
```

#### The Problem

The problem is that `new` value is not persisted to the database. Here is what I see in the log:

```
2019-11-30 12:19:40,065 DEBUG [org.acm.TestConverter] From JSON: {"value":"hello"}
2019-11-30 12:19:40,068 DEBUG [org.acm.TestConverter] To JSON: TestData{value='hello'}
2019-11-30 12:19:40,069 DEBUG [org.acm.TestConverter] From JSON: {"value":"hello"}
2019-11-30 12:19:40,071 DEBUG [org.acm.Service] Modified: TestEntity{id=2, data=TestData{value='new'}}
```

Here is the log file with hibernate logging turned on (too much to pase here so I'm posting a link): https://pastebin.com/1e3URx8W

#### What I've Tried

Here's some things I've tried:

- Adding `entityManager.persist(entity);` to the end of `modify` function -> **no change** (expected)
- Adding log entry to `TestData.equals` function -> **no entry in the log**
- Adding `entity.setData(entity.getData());` to the end of `modify` function -> **no change**
- Changing JSON type to TEXT -> **no change**
- Manually starting and commiting transaction -> **no change**
- Adding `temp = entity.getData(); entity.setData(null); entity.setData(temp);` to the end of `modify` function -> **working the correct value is persisted to database**

Is there anything I'm missing here?

Thanks

#### Versions

- JRE 8
- Quarkus 1.0.1.Final
- Hibernate 5.4.9.Final
- MySQL 8.0.18

Comment: Could you try to disable option `hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit` and recheck your problem. As I see from your traces it's enabled now.

Comment: Is there a way to specify this as env variable or java parameter, because I cannot find the configuration in quarkus:https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config

Comment: This option should be specified in the `persistence.xml`. See [this](https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm)

Comment: Unfortunatelly its still the same

Comment: Are you sure that your transaction is committed at the end of `modify` method. I tried to use your jpa entity + converter and it works fine for me. Could you try explicitly begin and commit transaction as described [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/transaction#api-approach)

Comment: Yes, I ve tried that and its still the same. Funny thing is that if I `temp = entity.getData(); entity.setData(null); entity.setData(temp);` it works

Comment: Ive attached configuration if it helps

Comment: Ive also noted that even if I specified provider_disables_autocommit=false in xml, it still shows that `hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit` was enabled.  This setting should only be enabled when you are certain that the Connections given to Hibernate by the ConnectionProvider have auto-commit disabled.  Enabling this setting when the Connections do not have auto-commit disabled will lead to Hibernate executing SQL operations outside of any JDBC/SQL transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me as if the update is pending in Hibernate's cache. If you read the entity via the `EntityManager` or persist and flush (`EntityManager.persistAndFlush()`) after performing `entity.setData(temp)`, the cache should get flushed and you should see your changes in the database.

Quote from [quarkus.io](https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm-panache#transactions):

> JPA batches changes you make to your entities and sends changes (it’s called flush) at the end of the transaction or before a query. This is usually a good thing as it’s more efficient. But if you want to check optimistic locking failures, do object validation right away or generally want to get immediate feedback, you can force the flush operation by calling entity.flush() or even use entity.persistAndFlush() to make it a single method call.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately it doesn't work. The only workaround I currently have is setting `data` to null, then setting it to original value.